# how to alter column wiith auto increment

Tags: db2

How to alter existing column auto increment in existing DB2-Table?

Comment: Not clear what you want to modify/alter. What did you do? What error?

Comment: YOUR SHIFT KEY IS BROKEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created a table with a normal column, like an **id** column here:

```
CREATE TABLE demo_tab
(id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 col_txt VARCHAR(20)
);
```

but later you decided to have it like this one with the **GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY** clause:

```
CREATE TABLE demo_tab
(id int NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
 col_txt VARCHAR(20)
);
```

use this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE demo_tab ALTER COLUMN id 
    SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1);
```

and do not forget about reorganising the table:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE demo_tab');
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want modify your identityvalue try this

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ALTER COLUMN youridentitycomunname RESTART WITH yourcountervalue
```